# Is there a clean way to connect kubernetes with cloud autoscaling?

Tags: kubernetes, cloud, autoscaling

I would like to use kubernetes on any IaaS cloud (e.g. OpenStack, AWS, etc.) and have it scale up the pool of worker instances when it can no longer bin-pack new workload.

I hope there is a IaaS-independent integration/API to allow this. If not, an integration with a specific cloud is good too.

Comment: Autoscaling is one of the key features in Kubernetes cluster

Answer (score 1):

[Kubernetes cluster autoscaler](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/tree/master/cluster-autoscaler) is what you are looking for. It works with multiple cloud providers including AWS